# Sufficient condition for orientability of a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, surfaces, orientation

I'm trying to better understand surface integrals involving vector fields, and I require that the surface be orientable.  As I understand it, a non-orientable surface is one that does not have a unique choice of normal vector.

Although I'm certain that there are tons of subtlety to the definition, is the following a **sufficient** (if not necessary) condition:

Let $f(x,y,z) = 0$ be a surface.  Then $f$ is orientable over some domain $D$ if $\nabla f$ is a continuous function everywhere in $D$.

Comment: First of all, not $f$ is orientable but its zero level set $S$. Second, you should also assume that $\nabla f$ is nonzero everywhere on $S$. Then $S$ is orientable.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good to me.  But what happens when $\nabla f = 0$?

Comment: Then anything can happen: The level set can fail to be a surface and even if it is a surface it can fail to be oriented.

Comment: I see.  If I further restrict my surface, then, to surface that are of the form $z = g(x,y)$, then is it correct that: $f(x,y,z) = z - g(x,y) = 0$ is always orientable provided that $g(x,y)$ has continuous first partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes it is; it even suffices to consider merely continuous $g$ (provided that you use topological notion of orientability).

Comment: Great, thanks for the information.  If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Suppose that you have a surface $S$ in $R^3$ given by $S=\{{\mathbf x}: f({\mathbf x})=0\}$, where $f\in C^1$ and has nonvanishing gradient on $S$. Then $S$ is smooth (by the implicit function theorem) and oriented since its normal vector field can be given by $\nabla f$.
2. Without the nonvanishing assumption on $\nabla f$, $S$ may fail to be even a topological surface, can fail to be a smooth surface and can even be a smooth nonorientable surface.
3. If $S$ is the graph of a continuous function $g: D\to R$, where $D\subset R^2$ is an open subset then $S$ is always orientable since it is homeomorphic to $D$. If, in addition, $g\in C^1$ then $S$ satisfies the assumption of item 1 and hence, admits a normal vector field.